# Fixed Title Bar without css:fixed

Tags: javascript, css, fixed, titlebar

I need to create a css layout with two sections, a title bar and content.

The title bar needs to be 55px and the content fill the rest of the page. I cannot use the position:fixed element. I am currently using javascript to set the height like this:

```
document.getElementById("content").height = (window.innerHeight - 55) + "px";
```

But I would like to use an all css layout, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer browsers that support css3 it is, you can use the calc() function in css. In your case it would look something like:

```
#content
{
    height: calc(100% - 55px);
}
```

You can find more documentation [Over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript for this. Get to know with this example better - [100% height layout](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html). Worked for me numerous times.